# Alternative notation for maximum of a vector.

Tags: statistics, notation, descriptive-statistics

Do you know of a one symbol notation for $\max(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

For instance the mean is often denoted with an overline: $\overline{\mathbf{x}}$.

Alternatively, is the maximum associated to a letter or symbol, like the letter $\mu$ that often denotes the mean ?

Comment: So after browsing the internet for hours and talking to people, it seems like there is no conventional notation for the maximum that is only one symbol long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [$\ell_\infty$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions), which coincides with the maximum if the vector has nonnegative entries:
$$
\| x\|_\infty = \max_{1\leq k\leq n} |x_k|
$$

For the maximum of a statistical sample (of size $n$) specifically, you are looking for the $n$-th [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Notation_and_examples):
$$
X_{(n)} = \max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}
$$

Comment: Interesting, but I feel like it conveys a meaning that is specific to topology.
In my case, I look for a notation for the maximum of a sample. So using norms, that are more related to distance, might be a little bit misleading.

Comment: Topology, not so much, but I didn't get from your question that you were specifically looking for maximum of a sample. I've edited my answer accordingly. @boring_stack_user

Comment: Thank you for editing and providing an alternative notation. Unfortunatly that's still not what I'm looking for. My issue is that I have too many indices and exponents in my notations, so I'm looking for something that indicates maximum without using indices or exponents. Something like the overline or the usual µ that are used to denote the mean.

Comment: Well, you asked for a known notation for it -- this is the standard one(s) I am aware of. The fact that they are not as concise as you hoped, unfortunately, doesn't change that... There is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_maximum_and_minimum) specifically for the sample maximum and minimum, and no other standard notation is given. @boring_stack_user

Comment: Yep, I did some research before asking here, so I'm aware that I'm probably asking for something that doesn't exist :( Thank you for your time !

Comment: @boring_stack_user No worries. Good luck with the super/subscripts!